# reading monthly returns in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following monthly equity data in file "equity.dat":

```
2010-03,1e+06
2010-03,1.00611e+06
2010-04,998465
2010-05,1.00727e+06
2010-06,1.00965e+06
```

I am trying to compute the monthly returns using the following code:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
y = Return.read(filename="equity.dat", frequency = "m", sep=",", header=FALSE)
y

z = Return.calculate(y)
z
z[1]=0 #added this to remove the NA in first return
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in read.zoo(filename, sep = sep, format = format, FUN = FUN, header = header,  : 
  index has bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I checked out the formatting for Return.read when using as.mon and that is why am using yyyy-mm. should I be using a different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `?Return.read` the default `format.in=` here is `"%F"` which is not the format of your data so it will have to be specified.  Also the index must be unique (in this case its not) or else it must be aggregated as per `?zoo` and `?read.zoo` the latter of which it uses internally:

```
Return.read(filename = "equity.dat", frequency = "m", sep = ",", header = FALSE, 
  aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1), format = "%Y-%m")
```

We have used `tail` to define the aggregating function -- you may or may not wish to use something else.

Comment: thank you for the corrected code. I will also look up tail() as I have not used it before. By using the above aggregation, it is not generating the March returns and that is something I was trying to achieve by including the initial equity

Comment: Label the initial equity as February so you don't have two March entries.  In that case you won't need `aggregate=` .